# Установка Android Studio ошибка Main

Tags: android-studio

В чем ошибка не могу понять ??
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в заголовок вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Убери строку из `build.grandle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'//удали эту строку
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Проблема из-за того, что не получается получить библиотеку `junit`